# Connection must be valid and open in vb 2008

Tags: mysql, vb.net

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Public Class daftar

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim Cn As New MySqlConnection
    Dim str As String
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand
    Cn = New MySqlConnection("server=localhost;" _
       & "user id=root;" _
       & "password=;" _
       & "database=loginapp")
    Try
        Cn.Open()
        MsgBox("Connected")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Failed Connection " & vbCrLf & "Error Message : " & ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Peringatan")
    End Try
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", user.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", pass.Text)
    str = "INSERT INTO tbluser(Username,Password) VALUES (@id,@pass)"
    cmd = New MySqlCommand(str)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    MessageBox.Show("Insert Data Siswa Berhasil Dilakukan")
    Cn.Close()
End Sub
End Class
```

I have problem with "cmd.ExecuteNonQuery", it have a message "Connection Must be Valid and Open" can anyone can help me with this problem?

Comment: You're not assigning your open connection to your command.

Comment: Passing password info as plain text is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe you understand what the `New` keyword does. You're creating a new command and adding parameters to it and then destroying your work by recreating a brand new instance of `MySqlCommand`. In addition to that mistake you never set your command to use the connection you've opened. You'd better go read the docs again.